# Php Validation, how to check if something is an "elementary school number"?

Tags: php

I want to validate if something is an "elementary school number", meaning digits and (optionally) a decimal point only. All these values would return true:

0

14.395492

1.1

Php's `is_numeric` allows leading signs (+/-) and scientific notation, thus these would return true which I need to return false:

+1.3

123.45e6

It seems like there should be a composer package out there to do things like this, maybe I'll make one if there isn't already. Know any composer packages and if not, how could we accomplish this? Regex may be the only option?

Comment: Are you accepting data from a form?

Comment: @MehdiBounya no. But that could be a use case in the future. I want to be able to reliably tell if $x validates, regardless of the source of $x.

Comment: ok now if `123.45e6` is not allowed, is `123450000` allowed?

Comment: Absolutely. That fits the definition of "numbers and (optionally) a decimal point"

Comment: Another question, is forcing the input to be numeric an option? or you have to verify it.

Comment: Mehdi, doesn't matter either way. To "force" input to be numeric in this format then we need a function to validate that the input is in this format. But if your question regards user input in forms, then no, like I mentioned this data can come from many sources. Our own db, an api call, etc. I need a function to validate $x, without knowing if $x is already forced to be in some format or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

```
$re = '/^[0-9]+?\.?[0-9]*$/';
$str = '11111.11111143434343';
$num = 112;
$float = 12.121;
$noexp = .0;
$str_noexp = '.0';


var_dump(preg_match($re, $num) && !is_string($num));  //true
var_dump(preg_match($re, $float) && !is_string($float));  //true
var_dump(preg_match($re, $str) && !is_string($str));  //false
var_dump(preg_match($re, $noexp) && !is_string($noexp));  //true .0 is interpreted as 0.0 
var_dump(preg_match($re, $str_noexp) && !is_string($str_noexp)); //false
```

Comment: This will still allow `-5`

Comment: It does not allow strings. Test on https://www.regexpal.com/. Enable flags global and multiline to test.

Comment: Your example here on stackoverflow is a string: `$str = '11111.11111143434343';`

Comment: It does not make any difference whether the variable is a number or a numeric string. It will work.

Comment: I know. That's the problem :) As I stated in my question, we're trying to validate that the input is a number. String is not a number.

Comment: use `preg_match($re, $str) && !is_string($str)`

Comment: This regex validates `.0` as well.

Comment: `.0` is interpreted as `0.0` .

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, converting data is allowed, you can do it using **type casting**:

```
<?php
$input = "123.45e1"; // This is the input

$filtered = (float) $input; // We force the value to be a float

var_dump($filtered); // Gives: float(1234.5) 

?>
```

But if the input is invalid, the result is **0**, so you can't differentiate between an invalid input and a **0**

Comment: Of course php would make an invalid input result 0 instead of false. I guess we could check if $input = 0 first, then return true if it does?

Comment: @KayakinKoder but what if the input is originally **0**, how can you tell if it's a legit input or not?

Comment: Right, I mean can we check that the original input is 0? If the original input is 0, then validation passes. If the original input is not 0 but the filtered input *is* 0, then validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace everything that is not a number or a dot. And if you want, test if the final string is different, but I would accept anything that is not empty, for example a typo like 12.14a would become 12.14, or a negative would have the minus sign removed.

```
$str = '-12.14a';
$expr = '.0-9'; // dot and numbers
$final_str = preg_replace("/[^".$expr."]/", '', $str); // replace
```

Please note that this still accepts two dots, for example by mistake, etc.